# UI Tabs, ajax/JSON Request, data not showing in tab

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jquery-1.9/ui-1.9 with jquery-ui Tabs. However data isn't displayed in tabs-1.

What I'm doing wrong? Setting ui.ajaxSettings.dataType = "json" or "html" didn't help either. The REST-requested data is JSON and should be transformed to html afterwards.

My code is like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                ui.panel.html(
                        "Daten konnten nicht geladen werden. " + "HTTP Status: " + jqXHR.status + " " + errorThrown );
            });
        }
```

....

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="rest/cfehler/9410273345537">CFehler</a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Historie</a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Einzelfälle</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">           
        </div>
    </div>

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying you're trying to show what is in the div "tabs-1"? Because if that is the case, there is an easy solution.
add

```
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
```

right after .
That will display the content in tabs-1 before any of the ajax is loaded. Then all you have to do is add your content to tabs-1, and it will display whatever you want it to.